# Perl Hash Value

Tags: perl, perl5.16

Im trying to print perl hash value but its printing the ARRAY().

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %myHash) {
    my $val = $myHash{$key};
    print "$key => $val\n";
}
```

The Output is printing like

```
172  ARRAY(0x1c42548)
199  ARRAY(0x1c42638)
209  ARRAY(0x1c63360)
299  ARRAY(0x1c63390)
325  ARRAY(0x1c634e0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your values in your hash are themselves scalars pointing to arrays. Consider using `Data::Dumper` to print the value or if the elements of the arrays are scalars you can try something like the following.

The two builtin Perl collections, hashes and arrays, do not nest *directly*. They contain scalars which may be strings/numbers or references to hashes or arrays. There can also be references to functions and other more exotic things.

```
# Extract the array as an array and interpolate.

foreach my $key (sort keys %myHash) {
    my @val = @{ $myHash{$key} };
    print "$key => @val\n";
}
```

`Data::Dumper` exposes an option to sort keys.

```
# sample program using Data::Dumper

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

# obj is a reference to a hash.
my $obj = { 1 => 2, 3 => 4};

print Dumper($obj);
```

which prints

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 2,
          '3' => 4
        };
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how can i utilize Data:Dumper for Comparing hash{key} element with an array element? Actually i need to compare the hask keys with an array element, also hash value with an array element. Like for example : array[0] = 10, i need to compare the 10 is greater than equal to hash of key && 10 is lesser than equal to hash of value. Could u please let me know how can i utilize Data:Dumper for the same ?

Comment: @JohnLevin You can't use `Data::Dumper` for anything except to display data.

Comment: (To clarify -- while `Data::Dumper` is a tool that can [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) data, it only produces a string that represents data and cannot be used for other purposes)

Comment: @JohnLevin, I think your follow-up question is more appropriate as a second question. Please include a bigger example with the input hash of arrayrefs and the expected output and what you tried.